# Windows version of Linux 'Monospace' font

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, debian

I'd really like a Windows version of the 'Monospace' font. In other words that exact font, I don't mean 'I want a monospaced font for Windows'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a good chance the Linux machine was using [DejaVu Sans Mono](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page), which is based on Bitstream Vera Sans Mono (also often used on Linux machines), but has better Unicode support.